# Why does the module name have to be passed in as a seperate argument when spawning python?

Tags: python, node.js, module, spawn

I ran into this odd scenario while trying to get modules working with python-shell ([see issue 
 #7](https://github.com/extrabacon/python-shell/issues/7#issuecomment-448295115))

Demo: https://repl.it/@almenon/FabulousFocusedDiscussion?language=nodejs

**This works:**

```
let childProcess = require('child_process').spawn("python", ["-m", "timeit", "-n 1", "'x=5'"]);
```

**This doesn't work:**

```
let childProcess = require('child_process').spawn("python", ["-m timeit", "-n 1", "'x=5'"]);
```

Will result in error:

> "C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe: No module named timeit"

What is going wrong?